How many energy bands does the free particle have?
The free particle Hamiltonian in position space is
$$H := -\frac{\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2 $$
with energy eigenvalues $E_\vec{k}$. To my eye, this means that there is a single energy band for the free particle. However, in resources like Girvin & Yang, they describe the free particle as having multiple energy bands.
So, how many energy bands does the free particle have?

G&Y is talking about condensed matter; your subject matter is not talking about free electrons in vacuum, but rather the free electron in a dense Fermi sea. That's different.

It depends on the zone scheme, no?!

I think you are not taking the notion of energy bands literally enough. If we accept that an energy band is defined as a "band" of energies, then what Tobias said seems to be in line with various resources.
In light of that, consider that an energy band literally means a band of energies, where band means some "continuous" curve of energy values (these curves won't truly be continuous, but we treat them as if they were here). Then, we can examine the various schemes in the image below (taken from these notes).

In the first image (a), we can see the free electron energy plotted against $k$ at one site. In (b), we see a periodic scheme where the same energies are plotted at all lattice sites. Finally, in (c), we see the reduced scheme where we bring everything back to the 1st BZ. Then, if we apply our notion of energy bands described above, (a) has one energy band, (b) has $2N-1$ bands where $N$ is the number of zones (move rightward and leftward and subtract one for overcounting the first zone by one). This gives us $3$ bands as shown in (b). In (c), we count the bands as described by the definition of "energy bands" presented and get 3, which is consistent with the periodic scheme. Thus, the number of bands seems to depend on the zone scheme.
